# how to make a VMware clone into a running instance from the command line?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I am using VMkfstools and the vim-cmd suite of programs to clone Linux hosts. I'm trying to figure out how to turn a clone into a new running instance, but for some reason I'm not locating any information on how to do it. I'm not seeing anything in the vim-cmd tools, and not finding anything in Google. Maybe my Google skills are sub-par, but in any case I'd appreciate some help.

**Additional info:**

one thing I noticed is that if I run the "clone" tool from the GUI (vSphere client), the resulting clone is automatically assigned a unique Vmid. But this does not happen when I make a clone using the VMkfstools from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer. It turns out cloning only creates the disks but does not create a new virtual machine. In order to use the cloned disks, they need to be attached to a new or existing virtual machine.